# Path error in accessing trained language data for OCR in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ocr

When I try to use a custom language in the ocr function as:

```
txt = ocr(img,'Language','path/to/tessdata/myLang2.traineddata');
```

I get the following error message:

```
 Error using coder.internal.errorIf (line 8)
    Unable to find path/to/tessdata/myLang2.traineddata. Make sure the path is  correct.
    Error in ocr>checkLanguage (line 281)
    coder.internal.errorIf(exist(lang,'file') ~= 2,...
    Error in ocr>parseInputs (line 185)
    [validLanguage, isCustomLanguage] = checkLanguage(userInput.Language);
```

The language file is in the folder "tessdata" and is added to my path so I don't understand what could be causing this to fail.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you need the specify the actual path, `path/to` is just an example.

Try `txt = ocr(img,'Language','tessdata/myLang2.traineddata');`

or type `which myLang2.traineddata` to get the full path.